# RxJava - как реактивно подставлять наблюдаемые значения (в т.ч. пары) в запрос в Room, который так же возвращает Observable?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, rxjava, livedata

Во вьюМодели:

```
val searchQuery = Observable<String>
val catNumberOnlyTurnedoff = Observable<Pair<Int, Boolean>>

fun getWords(query: String, category: Int, onlyOff: Boolean) : LiveData<List<Word>> = 
LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(wordDao.getWordsRx(query, category, onlyOff)
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST))
```

Запрос в dao выглядит так:

```
fun getWordsRx(
        query: String,
        category: Int,
        onlyOff: Boolean
    ): Observable<List<Word>> = blablabla
```

Как лаконичнее сделать чтобы при перемене какого-то из значений в Observabl-ах аргументов они автоматически подставлялись в запрос с соответствующими изменениями в передаваемом в Ливдату списке?